# Can you only use <nav> and <main> for div boxes?

Tags: html, css, box

I'd like to know if you can use other tags to make div boxes in html, or you can only use div, main, and nav without using the class tag?

I'm expecting there not to be one, but just in case, I was wondering if I could make div boxes without using class?

Comment: It's **really** unclear what you're asking. If you're after a list of generic container elements, see [Sectioning Content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Content_categories#sectioning_content)

Comment: Are you asking for alternative tags that can accomplish the div tag's purpose?

Comment: _class tag_? There is no class tag in HTML. There is only the class attribute.

Comment: Also, I just need boxes, not div boxes, srry i confused the 2

Comment: I need boxes to put images/text in

Comment: Sorry for the unclarity

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Although it won't be a div you can create boxes with other elements. Here is a very short list of other elements in html you can use:

- section
- header
- footer
- aside
- article
- code
- blockquote

The list goes on but if you would like your html file to be easily readable by others certain elements are used for certain areas of your html. If you would like to learn more [W3 School](https://www.w3schools.com/html/) and [freeCodeCamp](https://www.youtube.com/c/Freecodecamp/videos) are great resources to find out more about different elements and learn the way in which your html can be structured.

Hope I was able to help and have fun learning & creating!